# Parallel reading and processing from Postgres using (Py)Spark

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

I have a question regarding reading large amounts of data from a Postgres database, and process it using spark in parallel. Let's assume I have a table in Postgres I would like to read into Spark using JDBC. Let's assume it has the following columns:

- id (bigint)
- date (datetime)
- many other columns (different types)

Currently the Postgres table is not partitioned. I would like to transform a lot of data in parallel, and eventually store the transformed data somewhere else.

**Question:** How can we optimize parallel reading of the data from Postgres?

The documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) suggests to use a `partitionColum` to process the queries in parallel. In addition, one is required to set `lowerBound`, and `upperBound`. From what I understand is that in my case, I can either use the column `id` and `date` for `partitionColumn`. However, the problem here is how to set the `lowerBound` and `upperBound` values when partitioning on one of the columns. I noticed that data skew arises in my case if not set properly. For processing in Spark, I do not care about natural partitions. I just need to transform all data as quick as possible, so optimizing for unskewed partitions would be prefered I think.

I have come up with a solution for this, but I am unsure if it actually makes sense to do this. Essentially it is hashing the id's into partitions. My solution would be to do use `mod()` on the `id` column with a specified number of partitions. So then the `dbtable` field in the would be something like:

```
"(SELECT *, mod(id, <<num-parallel-queries>>) as part FROM <<schema>>.<<table>>) as t"
```

And then I use `partitionColum="part"`, `lowerBound=0`, and `upperBound=<<num-parallel-queries>>` as options for the Spark read JDBC job.

Please, let me know if this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to "partition" by the primary key column.

To get partitions of equal size, use the table statistics:

```
SELECT histogram_bounds::text::bigint[]
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'mytable'
  AND attname = 'id';
```

If you have `default_statistics_target` at its default value of 100, this will be an array of 101 values that delimit the percentiles from 0 to 100. You can use this to partition your table evenly.

For example: if the array looks like `{42,10001,23066,35723,49756,...,999960}` and you need 50 partitions, the first would be all rows with `id` < 23066, the second all rows with 23066 ≤ `id` < 49756, and so on.